# How to solve syntax/parse error in this line

Tags: php, syntax-error

This line in my code seems to be problematic.  Can anyone tell me or fix the syntax/parse error in it?  Thanks in advance.

```
echo "<td><div class="edit" id="div_1">".$row['title']."</div></td>";
```

Comment: Look carefully at your quotation marks.

Comment: you need to learn basics of PHP.

Comment: one of the ways `echo '<td><div class="edit" id="div_1">'.$row['title'].'</div></td>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the double quotes

```
echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_1\">".$row['title']."</div></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_1\">".$row['title']."</div></td>"
```